# Second level domains with Heroku and www redirection

Tags: heroku, dns, hosting, cloud, cname

I've been doing some reading on the fascinating subject of DNS, specifically the zone apex CNAME issue associated with Heroku and other cloud hosting platforms. Since Heroku strongly suggests never using A Records, what's the best way to use a second level domain with my Heroku app?

I found that certain paid DNS services like DNSimple that offer an "alias" record type (A Record masquerading as a CNAME) that allows you to map your second level domain to yourapp.herokuapp.com in an RFC compliant way. Unfortunately, I'm currently stuck with registrar DNS.

I did also try CNAME-ing a www subdomain as Heroku suggests, but there seems to be no ideal way to accomodate user typed urls with no www. The redirection service that my registrar (1and1) provides works, but paths are not preserved. For example, www.mydomain.com/about redirects to mydomain.com.

I'm hesitant to use a service like http://www.arecord.net/ because it seems like just another thing that could break.

Is there a better way to do this that I've overlooked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your registrar/DNS provider doesn't support ALIAS records or URL redirects at the DNS level, it's probably worth using A records on the root domain as a backup. At the application level, you can then redirect your users to the `www` subdomain.

The biggest risk is a potential outage on the IP addresses you point to on the root domain, but if you're primarily driving traffic to the `www` subdomain, and the A records on the root domain serve only as a backup, it might not be a huge deal. Even with the occasional outage or need to update the A records, it'd still be much more user-friendly than just rejecting root domain traffic.